# Electron + angularjs IPC mechanism

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ipc, electron

I am trying to use AngularJs inside Electron. What i'm confused about is, [the electron docs here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md#sending-messages) suggest on using something like:

```
// In renderer process (web page).
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')); // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg); // prints "pong"
});
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
```

> But since Angular is running inside the browser(webkit) I cannot essentially use `require` to get the ipcRenderer.

How would one overcome with this problem.

Comment: you probably want to use `contextBridge`, see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `require` in electron - it extends the webkit API with this functionality. Basically the whole NPM is at your disposal. Well, some thing will not work, obviously, but `require` will.

Comment: so in simple words, Electron extends the webkit itself to add functionalities like `require` etc?

Comment: Yep, adds that and a few more APIs.

Comment: Including the ipcRenderer functionality :D

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but you need to add **nodeIntegration**

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 632,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
```

in the BrowserWindow constructor